# AngularJS ng-view IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iis

I'm having an issue with the ng-view not display the views when im selecting them from the nav bar. I have this installed on an IIS server, so I'm not sure if there is something I need to change their either.

Config:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'MainWorkQueue.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/testingQueue', {
            templateUrl: 'TestingQueue.html',
            controller: 'testingQueueCntl'
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }]);
```

Index.html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp.controllers">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">BuRT</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Work Queue</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testingQueue">Testing Queue</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

When the page loads it loads the MainWorkQueue.html. When I select TestingQueue, the url changes, but the view doesn't.

Comment: Try changing your `href` tags to `href="/"` and `href="/testingQueue"`.

Comment: throws a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I run a similar code in my browser **Not Using IIS** it worked notice that I added on `<a href=#>` is now `<a href=#!/>` I used **!/** for links in angularjs

Comment: @Shortcircuit for run down on why Angular uses the # tag let me refer you to [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag). I hope this help you understand for future applications

Answer (score 0):

The first when condition is true because your URL of the `/testingQueue` has also a `/`. Changing the URL for your `MainWorkQueue.html` for example to `/main` should solve your problem.

And no, the IIS is not involved.

Comment: I added /main to the config and added main to the html code for that link. Didn't change anything.